# Getting $size count with a $cond of a lookup record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregation

Below is my query and data on Playgroun which works on two collections

[MongoPlayGroup Collection structure and Query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BvA0Q0f74dQ)

In the query im trying to add one more $match condition of something which return me the count of the subdocument i.e collectB after filter like below

```
{
   $match: {
          'collectB.finalValue' : 'Cost'
   }
}
```

Right now i get below result. I'm trying to add one more count column which would return count depending on the filter value of finalValue. Basically i want the count of record from _id =1

finalCount = finalValue : 'Cost'
count = All Record belonging to _id 1

[image: Response of query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the projection, you can use `$filter`

```
{
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      count: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$collectB",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.finalValue",
                "Cost"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "collectB.generated": 1,
      "collectB.finalValue": 1
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/afECyqyQ8zg)**